# jQuery Autocomplete get feeds from mysql DB

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

Do you have an idea how to pull data from mysql, put it in an array then feed it in an autocomplete field?

I have tried hardcoded the values but what I'm thinking is when I add a new record, I have to re-code again the array. I'm a newbie in PHP so I beg your pardon.

Kindly check what I've tried so far:

```
protected function jsGenerateResourcesAutocomplete(){


    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT employee_name FROM employee" ;

    mysql_select_db('test', $conn);
    $retval = mysql_query($sql);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval); 


    if(!$retval )
    {
        die('Could not select data: ' . mysql_error());
    } 

    $employeeNames = $this->employeeNames;
    $html = "";     $html .= 'var employeenames = [' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($employeeNames as $employeeName) {
        $html .= '"' . $employeeName-> $array . '",' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $html .= '];';
    $html .= '$(".resource-input input").autocomplete({source: employeenames});' .PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '});' . PHP_EOL; 
    $html .= '</script>' . PHP_EOL;
    return $html;
}
```

I believe something in this line:

```
$html .= '"' . $employeeName-> $array . '",' . PHP_EOL;
```

I have to put forth the array but I have no idea how to do it. Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what html does this output?

Comment: hard to understand your code.but if you want to make javascript array from php array. then you can use `json_encode($array);`

Comment: I still don't have an output. But using the hardcoded, it does the autocomplete.

Comment: @GBD I'd like to get the data from mysql, do you have an idea to do that?

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT employee_name FROM employee" ;

mysql_select_db('test', $conn);
$retval = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$retval )
{
    die('Could not select data: ' . mysql_error());
} 
$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)){
  $data[] = $row['employee_name'];
}

$html = "<script>";
$html .= 'var employeenames = '.json_encode($data);
$html .= '$(".resource-input input").autocomplete({source: employeenames});';
$html .= '});'; 
$html .= '</script>';
return $html;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it's now fixed, but the json_encode($data) doesn't show the autocomplete?

Comment: is this `SELECT employee_name FROM employee` query running directly in your database